# Question about calculating wash sales across multiple orders

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, calculation, wash-sale

How do I handle the accounting of my wash sales?

I bought AXP in 3 different orders, all purchased within 5 days of each other:

- 100 @ 122
- 100 @ 100
- 100 @ 76

I sold all 300 @ 102, and then repurchased the 300 shares the very next day @ 96.00.

Per IRS reporting, how do I calculate this as far as loss or gain?

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a “Best” Software to keep track of Wash sales?

Gainskeeper and Tradelog are two well known professional tax accounting software packages.  When I used to trade very heavily (100's of wash sales), I used Tradelog.  It did a better job reconciling trades than  my broker did.  I no longer use it and they are under new management so this isn't a current evaluation.  Programs like these tend to offer 30 day trials and and they offer  scaled subscription pricing, depending how many trades you do in a year.  You don't need any of these unless you're a frequent flier.

Comment: Thank you Bob- any thoughts on becoming applying and being recognized as a MTM Trader by the IRS-

Comment: @Randy - Trader Tax Status and its associated MTM accounting isn't easy to get approval for.  Here's some info from Green Trader (https://greentradertax.com/trader-tax-center/trader-tax-status/how-to-qualify/), a reputable tax site along with an article from Forbes magazine (https://www.forbes.com/sites/greatspeculations/2017/06/07/how-to-become-eligible-for-trader-tax-status-benefits/#b65ac2b3e354)